# Microsoft Access database worked before and now old records won't update

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, microsoft-access, query, asp

This code was working fine on Windows 2003 Server. Updated to Windows 2008 Server and now new records can be listed for update or delete but old records can only list record content, but can't be updated. I get the error below:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' 
Query-based update failed because the row to update could not be found. 
/admin/eventedit.asp, line 76
```